Gaussian integral with deplacement
I would like to solve exactly the following Gaussian integral:
$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |x^2-2| e^{-x^2/2} dx$.
I did not succeed with substitution. How can I approach this?

The absolute value is a pain so you want to get rid of it; split the integral into pieces depending on where it changes the sign. Equivalently, compute the same integral without the absolute value, then look at their difference.

Note that you are taking the integral of an even function.
(All integrals are $\int\text{something }dx$)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x^2-2|e^{-x^2/2}=2\int_0^\infty|x^2-2|e^{-x^2/2}$$
To compute this integral, we split into 2 parts:
\begin{align}&\int_\sqrt2^\infty(x^2-2)e^{-x^2/2}\\
=&\left(\left.-\frac{\sqrt\pi\text{erf}(x/\sqrt2)}{\sqrt2}-xe^{-x^2/2}\right)\right|_\sqrt{2}^\infty\\
=&-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2}-\frac{-\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-2\sqrt2}{2e}\\
=&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-\sqrt{2\pi}e+2\sqrt2}{2e}\end{align}
An antiderivative of $(x^2-2)e^{-x^2/2}$ is $-\frac{\sqrt\pi\text{erf}(x/\sqrt2)}{\sqrt2}-xe^{-x^2/2}$.
\begin{align}&\int_0^\sqrt2(x^2-2)e^{-x^2/2}\\
=&\left(\left.-\frac{\sqrt\pi\text{erf}(x/\sqrt2)}{\sqrt2}-xe^{-x^2/2}\right)\right|_0^\sqrt{2}\\
=&\frac{-\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-2\sqrt2}{2e}\end{align}
\begin{align}&\int_0^\infty|x^2-2|e^{-x^2/2}\\
=&\int_\sqrt2^\infty(x^2-2)e^{-x^2/2}-\int_0^\sqrt2(x^2-2)e^{-x^2/2}\\
=&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-\sqrt{2\pi}e+2\sqrt2}{2e}-\frac{-\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-2\sqrt2}{2e}\\
=&\frac{2\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-\sqrt{2\pi}e+4\sqrt2}{2e}\end{align}
So the final integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x^2-2|e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{2\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(1)e-\sqrt{2\pi}e+4\sqrt2}e$$
